# Why is the full subcategory consisting of simply connected spaces not complete?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Top}_*$ be the category of pointed topological spaces and $\mathbf{Top_1}$ the full subcategory of simply connected spaces. $\mathbf{Top}_*$ is complete and cocomplete. I am trying to show that $\mathbf{Top_1}$ is not complete.

If $X$ is simply connected but has a non-trivial $\pi_2$-group, then $\Omega X$ (the based loop space) is not simply connected. Also, $\Omega X$ is the pullback (in $\mathbf{Top}_*$) of the path space fibration $PX \to X$ along the map $* \to X$. For example, one could take $X = S^2$.

This shows that the pullback, if it exists in $\mathbf{Top_1}$, is not the same as the pullback computed in $\mathbf{Top}_*$.

Can I use this to show that the pullback doens't exist in $\mathbf{Top_1}$? Can I somehow show that if it did exist, then "it must be $\Omega X$"? Perhaps one can consider the relationship with the underlying sets, i.e. $\mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: It seems to me to be difficult to relate limits of simply connected pointed spaces with limits of their underlying sets. For one thing, the underlying set functor is not representable.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, yes. Is there another way of going about this then?

Comment: I've replaced $\mathbf{Top}$ (which almost always denotes the category of topological spaces) by $\mathbf{Top}_*$.

Comment: $\mathbf{Top}_1$ has products, right? Even infinite ones. So the only issue are pullbacks, or equalizers (these concepts are more or less equivalent if products exist).

Comment: I think an counter-example using the inclusion of $D^2$ into $S^2$ as either the northern or southern hemisphere and look at the equaliser of those two maps. Is this valid?

Comment: @JackDavies: If you could prove that the equalizer is preserved by the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Top}_1 \to \mathbf{Top}_*$, this would be a proof, because $S^1$ doesn't lie in the image.

Comment: As a warm-up, we should prove first that $\mathbf{Top}_0$, the category of path-connected pointed spaces, is not complete. Here, one could also guess that the equalizer of the two maps $D^1 \to S^1$ (which cover the circle by two half-circles) does not exist. But it doesn't suffce to say that the equalizer in $\mathbf{Top}_*$ is $S^0$. Perhaps someone wants to make an own thread for this question.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $\mathbf{Top}_0$ is complete. The limit of a diagram in $\mathbf{Top}_0$ is the path component of the basepoint in the limit of the diagram in $\mathbf{Top}_*$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a diagram of simply connected pointed spaces has limit $X$ in $\mathbf{Top}_*$. If it has limit $\tilde{X}$ in $\mathbf{Top}_1$ then there is a canonical map $\tilde{X}\to X$ that is the universal map from a simply connected pointed space to $X$.

The universal cover of $X$ (when it exists) comes close to this, but the failure of lifting theorems for spaces that are not locally path connected stops it working.

As noted in Jack Davies' comment, $X=S^1$ is the pullback of a pair of maps of simply-connected spaces. If a map $\tilde{X}\to X$ existed with the required universal property, then by considering paths (maps from $[0,1]$) and homotopies between them (maps from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$) it's fairly easy to see that it would have to be the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$. However, there are maps $Y\to S^1$ from simply connected but not locally path connected spaces $Y$ that do not lift to maps $Y\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you! I am a little confused by your remarks about how to show that the supposed map must be $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$. When you say "considering paths and homotopies..." is that in order to constructre a homeomorphism $\tilde X \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user50948 Exactly. By the universal property we get a continuous map $\mathbb{R}\to\tilde{X}$. By the homotopy lifting property for the covering map $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ we get an inverse (for a point $y\in\tilde{X}$ choose a path from the basepoint to $y$, map it into $S^1$ and lift to $\mathbb{R}$, this being well-defined since we can also lift homotopies between paths). The fact that this inverse $S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous follows from the fact a covering map is a local homeomorphism.